# golang: how to close the channel after all goroutines are finished?

Tags: go, concurrency

I would like to write a simple web scraper in Go by:

- get all href with a pattern from an URL
- extract some specific fields
- and write to a CSV file

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type Enterprise struct {
    name     string
    tax_code string
    group    string
    capital  string
}

var u, f string
var name, tax_code, group, capital string

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&u, "u", "", "Which URL to download from")
    flag.StringVar(&f, "f", "", "Path to the csv file to write the output to")
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func findHrefs(u string) map[string]string {
    resp, err := http.Get(u)
    check(err)

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(resp)
    check(err)

    e_hrefs := make(map[string]string)
    doc.Find("td div a").Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        e_href, _ := s.Attr("href")
        if strings.HasPrefix(e_href, "/Thong-tin-doanh-nghiep") && s.Text() != "" {
            e_hrefs[e_href] = s.Text()
        }
    })
    return e_hrefs
}

func fetch(url string, name string, file *os.File, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan Enterprise) {
    defer wg.Done()

    log.Println("Fetching URL", url)
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    check(err)

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(resp)
    check(err)
    e := new(Enterprise)
    doc.Find("td").Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        if s.Text() == "Mã số thuế:" {
            e.tax_code = s.Next().Text()
        }
        if s.Text() == "Tên ngành cấp 2:" {
            e.group = s.Next().Text()
        }
        if s.Text() == "Sở hữu vốn:" {
            e.capital = s.Next().Text()
        }
    })
    w := csv.NewWriter(file)
    w.Write([]string{name, "'" + e.tax_code, e.group, e.capital})
    w.Flush()
    c <- *e
}

func getDoc(u, f string) {
    parsedUrl, err := url.Parse(u)
    check(err)

    file, err := os.Create(f)
    check(err)
    defer file.Close()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    c := make(chan Enterprise)

    e_hrefs := findHrefs(u)
    for e_href, name := range e_hrefs {
        wg.Add(1)
        go fetch(parsedUrl.Scheme+"://"+parsedUrl.Host+e_href, name, file, &wg, c)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if u == "" || f == "" {
        fmt.Println("-u=<URL to download from> -f=<Path to the CSV file>")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    getDoc(u, f)
}
```

The problem is channel was not closed after all goroutines are finished and I have to press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get my shell prompt back:

```
2016/03/02 09:34:05 Fetching URL ...
2016/03/02 09:34:05 Fetching URL ...
2016/03/02 09:34:05 Fetching URL ...
^Csignal: interrupt
```

By reading [this](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines), I change the last line in `getDoc` func to something like:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}()
```

Now I can get my shell prompt back when running but the channel was closed before all goroutines are finished and nothing write to CSV file.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Send the process a SIGQUIT to find out where the goroutines are waiting. I don't see any code that receives from the channel.  Are the groutines stuck at the end of `fetch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it doesn't look like you're reading from your channel, and because it is a synchronous channel (you never declared a length on it) it will block if it receives a value. So you need to be reading from your `c` by `value <- c` or your fetch function will just hang at `c <- *e`

This is causing your `sync.WaitGroup` to never `wg.Done()` which never decrements the counter, which never causes the `wg.Wait()` to stop blocking, which causes your `close(c)` to never get called

Answer (score 0):

My original code is something like this:

```
e_hrefs := findHrefs(u)
w := csv.NewWriter(file)
for e_href, name := range e_hrefs {
    wg.Add(1)
    go fetch(parsedUrl.Scheme+"://"+parsedUrl.Host+e_href, name, &wg, c)
    e := <-c
    w.Write([]string{name, "'" + e.tax_code, e.group, e.capital})
    w.Flush()
}
wg.Wait()
```

and you can see, it's not concurrency.

I've just fixed by using the [range](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range) clause to iterate over channel:

```
e_hrefs := findHrefs(u)
for e_href, name := range e_hrefs {
    wg.Add(1)
    go fetch(parsedUrl.Scheme+"://"+parsedUrl.Host+e_href, name, &wg, c)
}
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}()

w := csv.NewWriter(file)
for e := range c {
    w.Write([]string{e.name, "'" + e.tax_code, e.group, e.capital})
    w.Flush()
}
```